Shell commands separated with && not working as expected
In my render.yaml-file (for deploying a dockerized Django app on render) I have the following line that is causing me trouble:
dockerCommand: "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn config.wsgi"

It causes the following error log: manage.py migrate: error: unrecognized arguments: manage.py collectstatic && gunicorn config.wsgi
I do not understand why this is happening. To be more precise: Why is the && not recognized properly as a command separator? It seems that instead it is ignored and the other two commands are misinterpreted as arguments for the first command?
Any help is highly appreciated

This is normal whenever there's no shell executing your command. Next step is to create one explicitly: sh -c 'a && b && c'

I'd argue that this question is mistagged -- it's not a bash question or a shell question, and the fact that it isn't is why you have a bug in the first place; if the command inside your yaml file were invoked via a shell this wouldn't have ever come up.

Thanks, that was quick! So what would I need to add to the command to have it executed in the shell?

...so you need to be asking about whatever specific CI/CD tool is reading the YAML file and running commands therein, since the details of how it's running commands is pertinent.

"What would I need to add" -- I already suggested sh -c '...'; that'll work if the command-line parsing is POSIX-y enough to recognize quoting. That's not a guarantee (we'd need to know the specific tool to be able to offer guarantees), but it's a pretty solid place to start.

Can you link to whichever tool it is that parses the render.yaml? Does it have documentation for the format of that file?

The documentation is rather sparse, all I've got is this: https://docs.render.com/blueprint-spec#dockercommand

...indeed, that's sparse enough that I'd probably call this worth a bug report, or at least a documentation enhancement request. The default behavior for a string given as a Docker command is to execute it under sh -c, and they should be documenting when they do something different.
